# Operaciones entre matrices

Tags: c++, array, matrices

Necesito realizar un programa que tenga las siguientes opciones del menú:

1. Producto por escalar
2. Suma de matrices
3. Resta de matrices
4. Multiplicación elemento a elemento
5. Suma diagonal
6. **Menor que** (El programa debe mostrar el número menor dentro de la matriz A.)
7. **Mayor que** (El programa debe mostrar el número mayor dentro de la matriz A.)
8. **Suma** (El programa debe retornar la suma de todos los elementos de la
   matriz A.)
9. **Promedio** (El programa debe retornar el promedio de todos los números de
   la matriz A.)
10. Para salir

Únicamente me faltan los puntos del 6 al 9, dejé en cada punto (del 6 al 9) la explicación de lo que debe contener.

**NOTA:**

1. Para realizar las operaciones correspondientes se deben crear dos matrices A y B
   de tamaño 20x20 y se deben inicializar con números aleatorios entre 100 y 200.

• Para las opciones que realizan operaciones únicamente sobre una matriz, se
debe trabajar la matriz A. Por esto se debe mostrar por consola la matriz A y
la matriz resultado.

• Para las opciones que realizan operaciones sobre dos matrices, se deben
trabajar las matrices A y B. Por esto se debe mostrar por consola la matriz A,
la matriz B y la matriz resultado.
• Cuando se ejecute una opción esta debe tener un título en mayúscula y
centrado.

• Para TODOS los casos (donde el usuario ingresa datos) se debe exigir al
usuario que los valores que ingrese se encuentren dentro del rango
establecido, en caso de que el valor ingresado se encuentre por fuera del
rango del programa se debe solicitar dicho valor nuevamente hasta que
ingrese el valor correcto.

adjunto mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //MENU//
    int menu;
    cout<<"Ingrese la opcion que desea ejecutar"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 1: Producto por escalar "<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 2: Suma de matrices "<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 3: Resta de matrices"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 4: Multiplicación elemento a elemento"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 5: Suma diagonal"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 6: Menor"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 7: Mayor"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 8: Suma"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 9: Promedio"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 10:Salir"<<endl;
    cin>>menu;
    
    int matrizA[5][5];
    int matrizB[5][5];
    
    while(menu!=10){
        switch(menu){
            case 1:{
                cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 1"<<endl;
                
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizA[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
                cout<<"matriz inicial: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              int mul;
                cout<<"ingrese el valor para multiplicar matriz: ";
                cin>>mul;
               cout<<"matriz multiplicada por: "<<mul<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]*mul<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
            
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 2"<<endl;
                 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizA[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizB[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            
            cout<<"matriz A: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matriz B: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matrices sumadas: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]+matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
            
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
               cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 3"<<endl;
               for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizA[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizB[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            
            cout<<"matriz A: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matriz B: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matrices Restadas: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]-matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
                break; 
            }
            case 4:{
               cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 4"<<endl;
               for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizA[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                matrizB[i][j]=rand()%100;
              }
            } 
            
            cout<<"matriz A: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matriz B: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
              cout<<"matrices multiplicadas: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                 for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                 cout<<matrizA[i][j]*matrizB[i][j]<<"\t";
                 }
                 cout<<endl;
              }
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 5"<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        matrizA[i][j]=rand()%100;
                    }
                    
                }
                int suma=0;
                cout<<"matriz inicial "<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                    
                        //suma de diagonal principal//
                if(i==j){
                    suma=suma+matrizA[i][j];
                }
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                }
               
                 cout<<"la suma de la diagonal principal es " <<suma;
                
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                cout<<"\t"<<"OPCION 6"<<endl;
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        matrizA[i][j]=rand()%200;
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        cout<<matrizA[i][j]<<"\t";
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                }
                
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                cout<<"OPCION 7"<<"\t";
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                cout<<"OPCION 8"<<"\t";
                break;
            }
            case 9:{
                cout<<"OPCION 9"<<"\t";
                break;
            }
            default:{
                cout<<"ingrese una opcion valida :p";
                break;
            }
            
        }
     cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese la opcion que desea ejecutar"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 1: Producto por escalar "<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 2: Suma de matrices "<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 3: Resta de matrices"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 4: Multiplicación elemento a elemento"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 5: Suma diagonal"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 6: Menor"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 7: Mayor"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 8: Suma"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 9: Promedio"<<endl;
    cout<<"<3 ";
    cout<<"OPCION 10:Salir"<<endl;
    cin>>menu;
    }       
            
            

    return 0;
}
```

psdt: en el código puse un tamaño de 5 x 5 únicamente para ir probando el programa, al verificar que todo esté en orden le cambio al tamaño pedido (de 20 x 20).
les agradezco si me pueden colaborar.
solo puedo usar elementos de las librerías mencionadas en el código.

Comment: Pero si lo que te queda es incluso más fácil de lo que ya tienes. Mayor y menos es parecido a sumadiagonal. Creas una variable y pones un if (variable<matrizA[i][j]){variable=matrizA[i][j]} . Suma es la más fácil de todas y promedio es igual a suma pero después divides por la cantidad total i*j

Comment: esque no me está saliendo :( jajaaj ya lo hice como dices y lo trate de hacer distinto, en el intento anterior me sale al primeer intento ya luego no me vuelve  funcionar ( o sale al contrario o sale un numero re largo negativo)

Answer (score 2):

Te aconsejo que las operaciones las lleves a cabo en funciones separadas, eso hará que tu código sea más limpio, legible, fácil de entender, fácil de depurar y menos propenso a errores.

Así pues, podemos empezar por definir el tipo de la matriz:

```
template <std::size_t ORDEN>
using Matriz = int[ORDEN][ORDEN];
```

Con el tipo definido, es muy fácil pasar la matriz como parámetro a una función, si además parametrizamos el tamaño la función será más flexible

```
template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int menor_que(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 100;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado = resultado < valor ? resultado : valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int mayor_que(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado = resultado > valor ? resultado : valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int suma(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado += valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
float promedio(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    return suma(a) / static_cast<float>(ORDEN * ORDEN);
}
```

Siguiendo ese consejo, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
using Matriz = int[ORDEN][ORDEN];

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
void randomiza(Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    for (auto &fila: a)
        for (auto &valor : fila)
            valor = rand() % 100;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int menor(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 100;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado = resultado < valor ? resultado : valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int mayor(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado = resultado > valor ? resultado : valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
int suma(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    for (const auto &fila: a)
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            resultado += valor;

    return resultado;
}

template <std::size_t ORDEN>
float promedio(const Matriz<ORDEN> &a)
{
    return suma(a) / static_cast<float>(ORDEN * ORDEN);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    Matriz<20> a, b;

    randomiza(a);
    randomiza(b);

    int menu;
    
    while (menu!=10)
    {
        cout <<
            "Ingrese la opcion que desea ejecutar\n\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 1: Producto por escalar\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 2: Suma de matrices\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 3: Resta de matrices\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 4: Multiplicación elemento a elemento\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 5: Suma diagonal\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 6: Menor\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 7: Mayor\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 8: Suma\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 9: Promedio\n"
            "<3 "
            "OPCION 10:Salir\n";

        cin >> menu;
        cout << "OPCION " << menu << '\t';

        switch (menu)
        {
        case 6:
            cout << "el número menor dentro de la matriz A: " << menor(a) << '\n';
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "el número mayor dentro de la matriz A: " << mayor(a) << '\n';
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "la suma de todos los elementos de la matriz A: " << suma(a) << '\n';
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "promedio de todos los números de la matriz A: " << promedio(a) << '\n';
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ingrese una opcion valida :p";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVVbb9MwFH6Of8WhiC3lItoNdkm7IgQ8TNpNm3hiaDp13GJw7BA7mxjar@KN1/2wcuykN2nZhhAIq1Vsn8t37uZ5/owr1OPJ5KHUXJWpgL401hUCswGb33EnM7F0YV2q5HDAWGmlHoPGTNgcuQAi9BhzIssVOuKkc5JYeSnOHBwev313MKhF9tEV8hJ2QGr3IVA@1p@75M@NTKFAnZpMXmJcKepXRFjBNvvOgNbIFBBj6QysjKTCBIgC9VqgnaOiQwKeZ87gV0XZCVBxGx5Bt9Ppsas7rCN3IBPaFDE32jpoMs/zFcKWymFqCCUonxteCd9m/iJHsxOLEPN9v3bu1cJdUt3VRhTClYWek@/pOH77bcf/oduDv@S2LTP8v7x@svOHbo2UQQd5YTKRSnOHc7X6EAZsw3OaAugkP@NoXT9oGsRBCB5X@tvBgKpipI69nsiGPvOTJj54v7fXJh4W1YhrnQHgUxj6q3nnI7EsHIdBou6/shcsY9HFJ6kExP7qwU6302YRYUXclA76fdpFrV09psAIUAgm59Jo@FoKSOkKQXwWvHRYnOpT3Qrc/XWoNodHb3YPD6CbwFFh0pJTanLKi7AclRe4mX0tgRMKE6kn18k3LmwT63oCx4IieR/eFwnsU2plriRHLq9/aBBKkNNkFc62TdIvp0ZJHBuNqolvg1D8aGuibxLdT4Am@laF00TeDqEMBdcY7U5ygkp6BJ/siEsNg0Gd8FlaYcre8gdP9N/VU7da94Nfkb2Qjn@qSoPKoqoLpELYSDzkTJdQoK9/ZqIw1WCnfGhHhzSUTFa9Y6@TGRhNQGqCAKhXvVXRkB7UL72p@s1m9T54t6sPA/ZW9VvL6kmHrQvOmdRYUPSfFoS9GWXayM0g28sg0zmxjFK71QAymy1NQKkYIdX0MpKsm7XUs26lQSdThCRvLctfMfrRgKiGk3@6J5MNtsm22Dbrdtgv)</kbd>.

Comment: `void` (vacío en inglés) es el tipo de retorno de una función que no retorna nada (no tiene `return` o el `return` está vacío). La palabra clave `template` es para definir una plantilla, las plantillas son una manera de hacer código genérico parametrizando partes de la plantilla. La cláusula `using` se puede usar a partir de C++11 para crear un alias de un tipo, es un `typedef` más potente.

Comment: :( sigo sin entender, lo que pasa es que unicamente debo utilizar expresiones de las librerias que mencioné , nada fuera de: if, switch, while, double, char, int, for, cout, cin... asi como lo tengo en el codigo, tal vez este desordenado pero el profesor no nos ha explicado otra manera de hacerlo, se notaria mucho si me baso en otros conceptos. sin embargo muchas gracias por tu ayuda :3

Comment: `if`, `switch`, `while`, `double`, `char`, `int`, `for` no son librerías, son estructuras de control y tipos. `cout` y `cin` no son librerías, son instancias de `ostream` e `istream` de las cabeceras estándar. Todas esas cosas son tan estándar como `template`. No puedo responder con detalle en un comentario limitado, si tienes dudas concretas te animo a que abras una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster es perfecta, pero solo a modo de ayudar al OP:

1. Lo primero es que tienes que poner variables a los rangos de las matrices, de lo contrario es de locos cambiar su dimensión
   Ocuparemos las variables X e Y

```
int main()
{
  // ... varías lineas de código aqui
  int X = 5;
  int Y = 5;
  int matrizA[X][Y];
  int matrizB[X][Y];
    
    while(menu!=10){
        switch(menu){
   // El resto del código aquí....
```

Entonces los for te quedán así:

```
 for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<Y;j++){
      //alguna operación acá
  }
}
```

Ahora si deseamos cambiar las dimensiones de las matrices, solo cambiamos los valores de X e Y, sin cambiar todo el resto del código

2. Menor que

Los array se recorren con un for, las matrices con 2 for, los cubos con 3 for y así sucesivamente. Esto, al parecer lo tienes claro.

Entonces queremos encontrar "el menor", el algoritmo es fácil: Tomamos el primer número, y lo comparamos con el siguiente.

- Si el siguiente es menor, nos quedamos con ese y seguimos comparando
- Caso contrario, nos quedamos con el que ya teníamos

```
 int menor = matrizA[0][0]; // tomamos el primero
 for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<Y;j++){
      if(matrizA[i][j]<menor) //comparamos con el siguiente. Excepto la primera vez, ya que en rigor es el mismo
      {
         menor = matrizA[i][j];
      }
  }
}
cout<<menor<<"\t"; //el menor
```

3. Mayor que

Igual al anterior, solo cambia el if. Te lo dejo para que lo resuelvas tu

4. Suma

También es lo mismo. Pero en vez de "quedarte con el anterior", le sumas el valor

```
 int suma= 0; // empezamos en cero
 for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<Y;j++){
      suma = suma + matrizA[i][j]; //a la suma le sumamos el valor actual (gracias a la asociatividad de la suma)
  }
}
cout<<suma<<"\t"; //la suma
```

5. Promedio

Ahora ya sabes sumar el contenido de una matriz. El promedio seria

```
  int promedio = suma / (X*Y);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias ya entendí, si esque era por los elementos como no me han explicado no entendia. pero ahora si, gracias por la ayuda ♥