# mejora de código

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes quisiera saber si mi código se puede optimizar o se puede quedar así como lo tengo, la verdad estoy empezando y este código lo tengo que exportar a .cpp y crear otro programa que lo lea cuando seleccione la opción en otro menú, tiene que cargar este menu sobre vectores

También tengo que crear otros códigos para otros menus de otros ejercicios y también unirlos en el menu principal. Espero me puedan ayudar

```
int tamvector=0, n,n1,n2,medida;
int menu ()
{
int opciones;
    cout<<" ------- MENU DE VECTORES ------- "<<endl;
cout<<"\t 1) Insertar valores de un vector "<<endl;
cout<<"\t 2) Búsqueda de valores en un vector "<<endl;
cout<<"\t 3) Mostrar valores del vector "<<endl;
cout<<"\t 4) Regresar al menu principal "<<endl;
cout<<"\t \n INGRESE OPCION: ";
cin>>opciones;
return opciones;
}

int main() 
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del VECTOR: "<<endl;

    cin>>tamvector;
    int numeros[tamvector];
    int valor;
 switch (menu ())
        {
            case 1:
            cout<<"1. Insertar valores de un vector "<<endl;
            for (int medida = 0; medida <= tamvector-1; medida++)
            {
                cout<<"Inserte un numero:"<< medida +1 << endl;
                cin>>numeros[medida];
            }   
            break;
            case 2:
            cout<<"2. Búsqueda de valores en un vector "<<endl;
            cout<<"Ingrese el numero a buscar "<<endl;
            cin>>n1;
            for (medida=0; medida<numeros[medida]; medida++)
            {
                if(numeros[medida] == n1)
                {
                    n2=medida;
                    n++;
                }
                }
                if(n>0 )
                {
                    cout<<"El valor se encuentra en la posicion: "<<n2<<endl;   
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"El valor no se encuentra en el vector: "<<n2<<endl;  
                }
            break;
            case 3:
            cout<<"Los valores del vector son: "<<endl;
                for (int medida = 0; medida < tamvector; medida++)
                cout<<numeros[medida]<< endl;
            break;
            default:
            break;
            system("cls");
        }
            getch ();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Lee esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/564658/301324 puede orientarte

Comment: Hablando de optimizar me parece que no hay casi nada que hacer. Solo déjale al compilador hacer lo que mejor sabe hacer. Si se podrían hacer mejoras para que el código sea más limpio, que es más importante que un código inentendible.

Answer (score 0):

**Variables globales**

Lo primero que yo haría es eliminar las variables globales. Las variables globales son peligrosas principalmente porque no tienes ninguna forma de regular el acceso a las mismas. En un programa sencillo puede que no pase nada, pero conforme el sistema va ganando complejidad, las variables globales empiezan a ser un foco de errores.

**VLA**

En C++ los arrays deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, es decir, su tamaño debe ser constante desde el mismo momento en el que escribes el programa. Sin embargo, el tamaño del array que tu usas depende de una variable.

Esto se conoce como VLA o *Variable Length Array*. **No lo uses**. Mis razones son las siguientes:

- No está soportado por el estándar, si te funciona es porque el compilador le da soporte. En consecuencia tu código no es portable, es decir, al compilarlo en otra máquina, usando otro compilador, puede no compilar o comportarse de forma diferente
- Los array se crean en la pila, una región de memoria de tamaño bastante limitado. Si la pila se llena, el programa deja de funcionar. Para almacenar colecciones de elementos mejor usa memoria dinámica

**Contenedores**

C++ es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, por ello pone a tu disposición una serie de funciones y objetos básicos. Entre estos objetos básicos se encuentran los contenedores, una colección de clases para almacenar listas de elementos:

- `std::vector`: Lista sin ordenar de tamaño variable
- `std::array`: Lista sin ordenar de tamaño fijo (reemplazo del array)
- `std::list`: Lista enlazada
- `std::set`: Lista ordenada de tamaño variable (sin duplicados)
- `std::unordered_set`: Lista ordenada de tamaño variable (con duplicados)
- `std::map`: Diccionario (sin duplicados)
- `std::unordered_map`: Diccionario (con duplicados)
- ...

Hay tantos porque cada uno está pensado para cubrir necesidades específicas. Estos contenedores te evitan lidiar con la gestión de la lista y la memoria dinámica. Es código muy probado y robusto que de seguro se comportará mucho mejor que cualquier implementación que puedas hacer tu solo.

**Usa funciones**

Vale que tu programa es muy cortito, pero hay que aprender a dividir el código.  Las funciones son imprescindibles cuando el programa empieza a crecer. Si las funciones han sido diseñadas con cabeza, el programa podrá ser mejorado de forma más sencilla.

**Tabula el código**

Tabular y alinear correctamente el código permite repasarlo y leerlo de forma más cómoda.

Si no respetas la tabulación dependerás del compilador para chivarte que faltan llaves y paréntesis ... y vete tu a saber dónde deberían ir colocados en ese caso!!!

**Comprueba las entradas del usuario**

NUNCA jamás debes confiar en el usuario. Si, por ejemplo, al usuario le pides un número, tu programa debe estar preparado para cuando le llegue un texto o un número negativo, o un número muy grande, o ...

Esto no quiere decir que el usuario sea tonto, pero puede confundirse o puede ser un hacker que intenta vulnerar tu programa para acceder al sistema, quien sabe.

Confiar en el usuario es la receta perfecta para que tu programa se rompa a nada que el usuario trastee un poco.

**No abuses de endl**

`std::endl` suena muy bonito pero esconde un efecto secundario importante, y es que al usar `std::endl`, el buffer volcará su contenido a la salida que corresponda (en el caso de `cout` a la salida estándar).

Ten en cuenta que los *streams* tiene buffers para mejorar el rendimiento del programa. Así, por ejemplo, la salida estándar no se tiene que actualizar a cada caracter que se escriba (operación muy lenta).

Forzar refrescos innecesarios acaba con la funcionalidad del buffer. En el caso de este programa el efecto es imperceptible, pero preguntas cómo mejorar el código y eso, entiendo yo, implica hacer uso de buenas prácticas.

Salvo casos muy concretos, es preferible usar `\n` en vez de `std::endl`

**Un ejemplo**

Aplicando un poco todo esto podríamos tener algo parecido al siguiente código

```
int leerNumero(std::string const& texto)
{
    int numero = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << texto;
        std::cin >> numero;

        if (std::cin.good())
            break;

        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.clear();
    }

    return numero;
}

int menu()
{
    std::string texto_menu = " ------- MENU DE VECTORES ------- \n"
                            "\t 1) Insertar valores de un vector \n"
                            "\t 2) Búsqueda de valores en un vector \n"
                            "\t 3) Mostrar valores del vector \n"
                            "\t 4) Regresar al menu principal \n"
                            "\t \n INGRESE OPCION: ";

    int opcion;
    do
    {
        opcion = leerNumero(texto_menu);
    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 4);

    return opcion;
}

void rellenarVector(std::vector<int> & numeros)
{
    std::cout << "1. Insertar valores de un vector \n";
    int medida = 1;
    for (int & numero : numeros)
    {
        numero = leerNumero("Inserte un numero:" + std::to_string(medida) + '\n');
        medida++;
    }
}

int buscarValor(std::vector<int> const& numeros, int valor_a_buscar)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<numeros.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numeros[i] == valor_a_buscar)
            return static_cast<int>(i);
    }

    return -1;
}

void imprimirVector(std::vector<int> const& numeros)
{
    for (int numero : numeros)
    {
        std::cout << numero << '\n';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    int tam_vector = leerNumero("Ingrese el tamaño del VECTOR: \n");

    std::vector<int> numeros(tam_vector);

    int opcion = 0;
    while (opcion != 4)
    {
        opcion = menu();
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                rellenarVector(numeros);
                break;

            case 2:
            {
                std::cout << "2. Búsqueda de valores en un vector \n";
                int valor_a_buscar = leerNumero("Ingrese el numero a buscar: ");
                int pos = buscarValor(numeros, valor_a_buscar);
                if (pos != -1)
                {
                    std::cout << "El valor se encuentra en la posicion: " << pos << '\n';
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "El valor no se encuentra en el vector \n";
                }
                break;
            }
        
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Los valores del vector son: \n";
                imprimirVector(numeros);
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```